# Variety with loops-elementary algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Im interested in polynomials $p(x,y)$ such that $V=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\, p(x,y)=0\}$ has at least one loop,i.e. simple closed curve. What kind of polynomials have this property?does this type of polynomials have a special name?

Comment: The subject you're looking for is called real algebraic geometry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry) and it has a very different flavor from ordinary algebraic geometry; the methods used to study it are almost totally different. This particular question is related to Harnack's curve theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack%27s_curve_theorem) and also Hilbert's 16th problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_sixteenth_problem) so those might be good keywords for further searches.